# Cómo firmar una app en modo release para playstore

Tags: flutter, vscode

Estoy subiendo una app a Playstore pero me indica que mi app fue firmada en modo debug, estoy utilizando vs code, las soluciones las encuentro usando Android studio

Seguí los pasos de este video https://youtu.be/Xgz8d5dy88g y firma sin problema pero según esto, en modo debug

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitás es primero generarte la clave con [keytool](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle), es por command prompt, no importa si tienes Android Studio o Visual.

Luego si [vincularlo](http://android/key.properties) a la app en android/key.properties

Por último, para este tema, modificar el android/app/build.gradle y especificamente en el [paso 2](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle)

Luego ejecutar el comando `flutter clean` en consola y no olvidar tampoco no subir este archivo del keystore de forma pública.

Espero te sirva la info.

Saludos
Martin

Comment: Gracias!  Luego de tantas vueltas salió el problema, estaba en la ruta del keytool.properties

Comment: Me alegro que sirviera!